# SQL Server / XML: change level of nested query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, subquery

can someone tell me how I have to change the following so that the results of the nested query (`items`) appear one level below `dateRange` instead of on the same level (which is what I get at present) ?

**My SQL:**

```
SELECT      A.dateRange,
            (
                    SELECT      B.item,
                                (
                                        SELECT      COUNT(*) AS volume
                                        FROM        LogEsc C
                                        WHERE       C.policy = B.item
                                        AND         C.EID LIKE 'PE%'
                                        AND         C.dateEsc LIKE A.dateRange + '%'
                                        FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
                                )
                    FROM        @temp2 B
                    ORDER BY    B.ranking, B.item
                    FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            ) AS items
FROM    @temp A
FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```

**My current XML:**

```
  <dateRange>2014-04</dateRange>
  <items>
    <item>EIA</item>
    <volume>17</volume>
    <item>CG</item>
    <volume>12</volume>
    <item>T</item>
    <volume>10</volume>
    <item>AD</item>
    <volume>9</volume>
    <item>IR</item>
    <volume>9</volume>
    <item>AS</item>
    <volume>8</volume>
    <item>A</item>
    <volume>8</volume>
    <item>FS</item>
    <volume>6</volume>
    <item>AP</item>
    <volume>5</volume>
    <item>DG</item>
    <volume>5</volume>
  </items>
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `AS items` to `AS [dateRange/items]`.

Comment: Thanks for this ! This moves items under dateRange but then has all the items in one row. Is there a way to do the same but have each item appear in a separate row (below items) ?`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "in one row".

Comment: Looks like I can actually work with this. Let me do some more tests.

Comment: This works absolutely great - really like the approach ! Thanks a lot for this !